# Counting frequency of second elements in list? (Python)

Tags: python, list

I want to be able to output the number of times the second-position numbers occur. For instance:

```
L=[['a',1], ['b',2], ['c',2], ['d',5]]
```

And the counter would return:

```
1: 1 time(s)
2: 2 time(s)
5: 1 time(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#counter-objects) exists for precisely this kind of work:

```
>>> collections.Counter(i[1] for i in L).most_common()
[(2, 2), (1, 1), (5, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

appearances = defaultdict(int)

for i in L:
    appearances[i[1]] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 2], ['d', 5]]
>>> for n, c in Counter(n for c, n in L).most_common():
        print '{0}: {1} time(s)'.format(n, c)


2: 2 time(s)
1: 1 time(s)
5: 1 time(s)
```